# setting up a linux machine on a webserver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, heroku, ssh, webserver

I have a server with Hostinger, and I have SSH access.
It lacks a LOT of commands. Here's my bin folder.
https://gyazo.com/4509a9c8868e5a19c01f78ba3e0bf09e
I can use wget, meaning I can grab packages.

How can I get this up and running as an average linux machine? My plan is to use heroku on it (sneaky i know) and run django and such, but it lacks so much to start with it's looking really hard. I'm lacking essentials, including dbkg, apt, make, ect. Tips are appreciated.

Comment: What does "My plan is to use heroku on it" mean? Heroku is a host on its own; you don't need another host like Hostinger to work with Heroku. "I'm lacking essentials, including dbkg, apt, make, ect."—that's not unusual for shared hosting. To get full root-level OS access you may want to use a VPS (and even then you may not have `dpkg` depending on the OS). But again, I'm not sure how this has anything to do with Heroku.

Comment: @Chris Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm planning to use the webserver as hosting, if that would work. Mostly, I need django. I think I have a misconception of what Heroku is. In a way, I mean I want to host an apache server on the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a case when your Linux based server is missing core packages like package manager (As I understood you don't have apt-get).

> I'm lacking essentials, including dbkg, **apt**, make, ect.

For me, this server is broken and needs to be reinstalled.
I guess you can try to install apt with wget:

- look for apropriate release here: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/
- Example: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.7.0_amd64.deb`
- Install `dpkg -i apt_1.4_amd64.deb`

But maybe you are on different OS than you think? Have you tried to install with yum or dnf? To make sure what os you run type:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

or

```
lsb_release -a
```

Going back to your question on how to setup Linux server.

#### 1. Update

```
[package manager] update
```

If you run Debian based OS use **apt-get** as a package manager, if Centos based use **yum** or **dnf** (dnf is updated yum) and **Arch uses pacman**. For other distributions look it up.

#### 2. Install

Install packages you require. To make life easier you can install groups

```
yum groupinstall [name_of_group]
```

For my knowledge apt doesn't have group install but uses meta packages instead (They points to a group of packages) Ex.:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

#### 3. Create users

Avoid using root! Create users for services, processes etc. This is tremendously important for security reasons. [More on overall security for Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html)

#### 4. Configure

Mayby silly point but configure what needs to be configured. For instance, web servers, ssh, workspace etc. Each use case is different.

#### 5. Orchestrate

If you don't want to set up each time Linux environment by hand from shell you can use tools like [Chef](https://docs.chef.io/platform_overview.html) or [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/resources/get-started) for doing it for you (Of course you need to configure it first which will take some time, but later you will save much more trust me)

For setting up application environments, I really recommend using [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/). Thanks to this your application will work on any Linux based server which has docker engine installed. Not only maintenance, but deployment will also be child easy. Just download on any server your image, then run container with necessary parameters.
At the end you will need any server with only security, kernel updates and docker engine. Rest of dependencies will be resolved inside your Docker image

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunatly, I don't have a /etc/*release, and yum and dnf don't work. Also, to install apt, i don't have dpkg, meaning I can't actually install it. Any other ways to get my hands on apt?

Comment: To add, I also do not have gdebi.

Comment: "For me, this server is broken and needs to be reinstalled."—that's not necessarily the case. OP may be using a shared hosting environment where these utilities are deliberately not made available. I don't think OP has _access_ to reinstall the server. And even with root access `dpkg` may not be available. There are several package managers for Linux besides `dpkg` / `apt`.

Comment: @Chris In that case yes. But as I understood OP was referring to Linux server from some service provider which he maintains. Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but if in fact, he's using shared hosting env I don't think so there is much he can do.

Comment: @SpicyNachos Can you explain what is yor use case? Do you want to just run diango app on some server?

Comment: Thank you very much lads, but I kind of ditched the server. The server I was refering to is a cpanel based webserver, with ssh access. I was hoping to renovate it into some sort of VPS, but I stopped and just bought a vps from Digital Ocean.

Comment: If you need this server just for learning/development purposes and you don't need a lot of resources then you can get a [free year of Amazon AWS EC2 instance.](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku isn't a web server in the same sense as Apache or Nginx. It's a [platform  as a service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) provider. You don't install it on your own server, you use its hosted platform (and it uses whatever web server you bundle into your slug).

I suggest you go through the [getting started tutorial for Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python), which walks you through deploying a simple Django app on Heroku. That should give you a good idea of how Heroku works.

If your goal is to enable some kind of deploy workflow on your own server (via shared hosting or a server where you have full administrative access) you can  search the web for deploy tools. There are all kinds of them, some of which may be more suitable to your needs than others.